# What's the meaning of [MaxLength]="this['point']" in angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I encountered this piece of code `[MaxLength]="this['point']"`in angular `template`.
I don't know how to find out the meaning online.
I know the meaning of [property]="fieldOnComponent".
But I'm wondering why using `this` and `['']` in the code.
What's the syntax associated with this?

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Answer (score 1):

It is undocumented feature that let you write code in template like

```
[x]="this.prop"
{{ this.prop }}
```

or using brackets notation

```
[x]="this['prop']"
{{ this['prop' ]}}
```

where `this` is component instance.

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Azg3NLK60Xl6J66tlCH0?p=preview)**

Support for `this` was [added in angular 2.0.0-rc.5](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/0ca05eee45c6fd1746900b19b142c1c03a125939).

Answer (score 0):

The notation

```
this['point']
```

is in Javascript (and thus, in Typescript, used in Angular, and also available in Angular templates) the same as

```
this.point
```

You can get more info about the subtle difference of the 2 notations here for example : [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

---

`this` refers to the component. Usually, you don't have to specify it in a template, and you should just write `point` instead of `this.point` . But if you want to use the `['point']` (bracket notation) instead of the dot notation, you *have* to specify `this` in this case.